# There is a missing element in my 2D array when it's printed

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MSIZE 10
int main()
{
    int Size, gen, i, j;
    printf("Enter number of generations\t");
    scanf("%d", &gen);
    printf("\nEnter size of the matrix (max size is %d and min is 2)\t", MSIZE);
    scanf("%d", &Size);
    if (Size > MSIZE)  {
        printf("\nSize should not be more than %d", MSIZE);
        return 1;
    }
    if (Size < 2)  {
        printf("\nSize should not be less than 2");
        return 1;
    }
    char **m = (char**) calloc(Size, sizeof(char*));
    for (i=0; i<Size; i++)
    {
        m[i] = (char*) calloc(Size, sizeof(char));
    }
    printf("Enter matrix of first generation\n");
    for (i=0; i<Size; i++)  {
        for (j=0; j<Size; j++)  {
            scanf("%c", &m[i][j]);
            /*to make sure*/
            printf("%c ", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

This is the first part of my program which should be about the death game for Conway. I think, the problem is in the input function, because if I fill it inside the program by myself (not by input) it will be printed right.

Comment: Any reason why you can't allocate this as a 2D array instead of a fragmented lookup table? That is: `char (*m)[Size] = calloc( 1, sizeof(char[Size][Size]) );`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think, the problem is in the input function, because if I fill it
>   inside the program by myself (not by input) it will be printed right.

You need a space before `"%c"` in [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) to consume a previous newline/enter:

```
for (i=0; i<Size; i++)  {
    for (j=0; j<Size; j++)  {
        scanf(" %c", &m[i][j]);
        /*to make sure*/
        printf("%c ", m[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

When you hit enter on the previous `scanf()`, a newline is placed in the input buffer. Adding a space in front of `%c` tells `scanf()` to skip that newline (and other whitespace).

Comment: Actually, this had solved my problem, now it's printed right, but can you explain why we did so.

Comment: @GloryAyoub When you use `scanf` the newline you use to enter data is also in the input buffer, and when you read a character the newline will be read. Adding a leading space will tell `scanf` to read and discard leading white-space. Note that it's not needed for e.g. the `"%d"` format, as that format is specified to skip leading white-space. I recommend you check [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), especially the paragraph below the format code table.

Comment: @GloryAyoub - See Joachim Pileborg's comment and the updated answer.